# How to use jquery .load to open modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I wrote a code so that I could open a modal once an image was clicked. For example if I clicked the life of pi book cover it would open a modal displaying information about it. But for some reason it doesn't work and I am not sure why. Also note that the life of pi only has a unique id because I was first testing it on just one image. The code is below

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $modal = $("#myModal");
  $("#lifeofpi").click(function() {
    $modal.show();
  });
  $modal.find('.close').click(function() {
    $modal.hide();
  });
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.review-img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class='images'>
  <img class="review-img" id="lifeofpi" src="./images/lifeofpi.jpg"></img>
  <img class="review-img" src="./images/kiterunner.jpg"></img>
  <img class="review-img" src="./images/starwars.jpg"></img>
  <img class="review-img" src="./images/twilight.jpg"></img>
</section>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the modal visible by changing the css attribute `display: none` with `show()`.

```js
$(function(){
  var $modal = $("#myModal");
  $(".review-img").each(function() {
    var $image= $(this);
    $image.on("click", function() {
      var url = '/bookDetails/' + $image.data("bookid") + '.html';
      // Test:
      url = 'https://httpbin.org/html';
      $modal.find('.modal-content p').html('Loading...').load(url);
      $modal.show();
    });

  });
  $modal.find('.close').click(function() {
    $modal.hide();
  });
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.review-img {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class='images'>
  <img class="review-img" data-bookid="lifeOfPi" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51atapp7YTL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="Life of Pi"></img>
  <img class="review-img" data-bookid="kiteRunner" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51MtGFNeYjL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="Kite Runner"></img>
  <img class="review-img" data-bookid="starWars" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51oqkfvEwZL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="Star Wars"></img>
  <img class="review-img" data-bookid="twilight" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41K99+cInvL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="Twilight"></img>
</section>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Book details loading...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you loading a html. Its css

Comment: The jQuery method `load` is to load content by ajax, you can simply remove it if you don't need it. css is automatically applied on page load and can not be "loaded" on a html element. Check my updated answer to close the modal.

Comment: the code that you just added doesnt work. So are you saying I cant use the .load method with a css file only html

Comment: I just added the html code of the modal into the question

Comment: My code works with your example, check my answer and click on "run code snippet". css is usually embedded with `<link>` tags if it's stored in a separate file or within `<style>` tags. You do not need JavaScript to apply css. This is the documentation of the `load` function you were using: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: If I wanted to add a modal on all the images how would I do it

Comment: Fabia H how would I add this function to all the images. All having different interior modal content

Comment: @Teoccis proposition is to store the information for the modal in the alt tag, if it's not too much content, that's fine. Why do you want to use the `load()` function, do you want to load the model content by ajax?

Comment: Yes Fabian H I want to load the modal content by ajax

Comment: I want it to do exactly what it is doing just using .load instead I will update my code in the question to show you what I have now. I have got the modal to work dynamically on all images which is good, but now I just want to load the modal content by ajax instead.

Comment: Voilà, here you go

Comment: Fabiah H The .load works but the all the images have the same content appearing in the modal. How would I make each image have different content.

Comment: this is a link to the js fiddle I have if you click on the image each image can have different text inside it. This is basically what I exactly want it to do just using .load instead  https://jsfiddle.net/x9bvLwjL/17/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137863/discussion-between-fabian-h-and-cars).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a dynamic way to do it. Here is my solution

**Note**: I edited because the images were so big.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $modal = $("#myModal");
  $(".review-img").each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    element.on("click", function() {

      var alt = element.attr("alt")
      console.log(alt);
      $modal.find('p').html('Some text in the Modal.. ' + alt);
      $modal.show();
    });

    $modal.find('.close').click(function() {
      $modal.hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.review-img {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 160px; // height
  //width: 30%; // width
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class='images'>
  <img class="review-img" src="http://i.imgur.com/t8SXpzI.jpg" alt="lifeofpi"></img>
  <img class="review-img" src="http://i.imgur.com/FqYNsbY.jpg" alt="kiterunner"></img>
  <img class="review-img" src="http://i.imgur.com/NCkqUVz.jpg" alt="starwars"></img>
  <img class="review-img" src="http://i.imgur.com/fDvqMaZ.jpg" alt="twilight"></img>
</section>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but I have to use query. load

Comment: if you show me your code probably I can modify my answer to meet your requirements ~

Comment: I have updated the code again but remember that I have to use jquery.load not what I currently have

Comment: What do you want o to load? I don't understand. The jQuery load() method loads data from a server (like another url) and puts the returned data into the selected element. So what do you want to load??

Comment: I want to load the modal

Comment: the modal doesn't need to be load. The modal is already in the page. That is why we use hide and show to update the visibility of the modal. As I told you, the load function LOADS an external URL. For example google.com

Comment: cant you load an external file such as movies.html instead of url

Comment: yes of course. that why I asked you to show me your code to see what you want to load.